# Select table adding columns with data depending on duplicates in other column

Tags: sql, teradata

Imagine this data.

| Id | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | B |

I want to select table and ad two columns turning it to this. How can i do it? (In teradata)

| Id | Type | Id with both A+B | Id with only A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | B | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | B | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | A | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | B | 0 | 0 |

Comment: I could also use a version where i ignore "type"-column and just say:

Case id-duplicates exists then 1 else 0

How would I write that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with teradata but in standard SQL next query should be working:

```
SELECT 
    T.*,
    CASE WHEN Cnt = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BOTH_TYPES_PRESENT,
    CASE WHEN Cnt = 1 AND Type = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ONLY_A_PRESENT
FROM T
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Id, COUNT(DISTINCT Type) Cnt FROM T WHERE Type IN ('A', 'B') GROUP BY Id
) CNT ON T.Id = CNT.Id;
```

[SQL online editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2019/bd6bc11b24be7f5b8d12700e5410cca6/)

Comment: Hi! Got a follow up question. In the data there are actually a type 'D' and 'E'. I only want Both_types_present if at least 1 is type 'A' or 'B'. How would i do that?

Comment: @MarvinJohannisson, please ask separate question followed by [mre], you cal post your tables and data on https://sqlize.online